# Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03) for Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode) on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, kernel, bluetooth

I have a bluetooth dongle `Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)`. It starts successfully but don't get available devices to pair.

This is output of `systemcctl status bluetooth.service`:

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2021-06-19 03:33:03 +0430; 5min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 30799 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 19005)
     Memory: 812.0K
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─30799 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

ژوئن 19 03:33:03 heydar-ThinkStation-P300 systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
ژوئن 19 03:33:03 heydar-ThinkStation-P300 bluetoothd[30799]: Bluetooth daemon 5.53
ژوئن 19 03:33:03 heydar-ThinkStation-P300 systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
ژوئن 19 03:33:03 heydar-ThinkStation-P300 bluetoothd[30799]: Starting SDP server
ژوئن 19 03:33:03 heydar-ThinkStation-P300 bluetoothd[30799]: Bluetooth management interface 1.17 initialized
ژوئن 19 03:33:03 heydar-ThinkStation-P300 bluetoothd[30799]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.73 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
ژوئن 19 03:33:03 heydar-ThinkStation-P300 bluetoothd[30799]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.73 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
ژوئن 19 03:33:05 heydar-ThinkStation-P300 bluetoothd[30799]: Loading LTKs timed out for hci0
ژوئن 19 03:33:13 heydar-ThinkStation-P300 bluetoothd[30799]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
ژوئن 19 03:33:24 heydar-ThinkStation-P300 bluetoothd[30799]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
```

`hciconfig hci0`:

```
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
        BD Address: 00:1A:7D:DA:71:10  ACL MTU: 640:4  SCO MTU: 64:8
        UP RUNNING 
        RX bytes:1238 acl:0 sco:0 events:73 errors:0
        TX bytes:2771 acl:0 sco:0 commands:75 errors:0
```

Comment: What do you see when you type `hciconfig hci0` into the Terminal? Does the system complain "No such device"?

Comment: added to question.

Comment: Hey @heydardasoomi , did you find a solution to this other than restarting the system?

Comment: @theProcrastinator no

Comment: Same issue, and same stalemate here also. Hmmm. Restart alone seems to fix it, but looking for an answer still

Answer (score 0):

I'm also experiencing this problem using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Error message:
`Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)`

Only solution seems to restart. After restart I seems to work for some time, then crashes again.

Edit:

What I Noticed is that it only applies when laptop is not in **charging** mode.

Answer (score 0):

Posting as an answer versus a comment because the question can likely be closed as duplicate from another Stack. This is a repeat of:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/602730/bluetooth-intermittently-disconnects

**Which is solved here:** https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/602739/115743

I would also flag the question, which was a good question, but a duplicate from across the network... thankfully! What a pain! Solved over at `Unix & Linux`.